# Impact of calling this.$scope.$digest();

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, signalr

I would like to know if there is any impact of calling         `this.$scope.$digest();` after every AJAX download of script. I am using SignalR to get data from server. No sooner the data comes in than I want to have the data painted to the grid. While my functions in controller js execute within a winking time of the eye, the painting to the UI takes around 3 to 4 seconds which is unacceptable.

Angular Batarang says 6.8 ms and 1542 watchers.

How do I optimize the page?

Comment: Is the bottleneck possibly just too many items to paint at once? Have you tried using the 'limitTo' directive or some other way to do local pagination?

Comment: Yes. I am applying limitTo as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible reasons for your issues. Either you are retrieving data very often, and trying to redraw it every time it is received. Or you are retrieving a lot of data and trying to update a control in your view that is very large. Here is how you solve both of these problems:

1. *Data retrieval faster than update speed*

For this you need to create a buffer between the retrieved data and the `$scope` data. Basically whenever you receive new data, you should push the changes to a data structure that isn't on scope. This way you can get data as fast as you want and it won't effect rendering. Then you need a heuristic for deciding when you want to redraw the data. This could be based on a timer, or something after data change. Once this condition is true, you copy the data changes over to your `$scope` object, which will update the view.

```
- receive data -> write to non scope buffer
- when some condition is met -> write buffer or buffer changes to $scope
```

2. *Data retrieved is large, and view is large and complex*

For this situation, your only option is to somehow simplify the view. With grids, this can be some sort of pagination or limiting constraint. There are plenty of angular grids out there that do these kinds of things, and I would just look for one that suits your situation better .

Comment: I think option 2 is out of bounds for our application because it is a log viewer. I think I should be going with option 1. Thanks for helping out.